# I'm trying to select few rows from mysql with LIMIT, but few records are missing if we change limit

Tags: mysql

Im fetching records from db with limit 0,10:

```
SELECT 
        p.*,
        s.name AS series_name,
        COUNT(distinct pv.id) as total_views,
        COUNT(distinct pl.id) as total_likes,
        COUNT(distinct pc.id) as total_comments
      FROM 
        table_one p
      LEFT JOIN
        table_two s
      ON
        s.id = p.seriesId
      LEFT JOIN
        table_three pv
      ON
        p.id = pv.postId
      LEFT JOIN
        table_four pl
      ON
        p.id = pl.postId
      LEFT JOIN
        table_five pc
      ON
        p.id = pc.postId
      WHERE 
        p.userId = 1 
      GROUP BY
        p.id
      ORDER BY
        total_views
      DESC
      LIMIT
        0, 10;
```

Now I Got the following records(Notice record with id = 34):
[records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBUcA.png)

Notice the record with id 34 is the 5th record and record with id 48 is the 6th record.

Now When I change the LIMIT to (0, 5):

```
SELECT .... LIMIT 0, 5;
```

I was missing that 5th record and 6th record(id 48) is coming as 5th record as below:
[records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49rf3.png)

And now when i change the LIMIT to 5, 5, the 6th record again repeated as 6th record as shown below and 5th record is missing.

```
SELECT .... LIMIT 5, 5;
```

[records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWD9g.png)

And user Id is 1, for record 5 which i was specified in the query.

Any help would be great.

I verified userId for the record with id 34.

Comment: Please watch the images with the link above with name records if you are not understand what im saying

Comment: What are the values for total_views for all the records?

Comment: It Will be integers. the count of total posts

Answer (score 0):

Using limits with group by and using counts for the purpose might not be a good idea.
What will happen when there are more than 1 items with same number of `total_views`
Anyway, Try using:

```
sELECT * FROM (SELECT 
        p.*,
        s.name AS series_name,
        COUNT(distinct pv.id) as total_views,
        COUNT(distinct pl.id) as total_likes,
        COUNT(distinct pc.id) as total_comments
      FROM 
        table_one p
      LEFT JOIN
        table_two s
      ON
        s.id = p.seriesId
      LEFT JOIN
        table_three pv
      ON
        p.id = pv.postId
      LEFT JOIN
        table_four pl
      ON
        p.id = pl.postId
      LEFT JOIN
        table_five pc
      ON
        p.id = pc.postId
      WHERE 
        p.userId = 1 
      GROUP BY
        p.id
      ) a
    ORDER BY
        total_views
      DESC
      LIMIT
        0, 10;
```

Let me know how it goes

Comment: It gave me the same result. record with id 34 is still missing